# How preview find file without close minibuffer

Tags: find-file, consult

```
Emacs 27.1
```

packages:

```
consult
embark
```

I want to find test.txt file in folder temp.

I do this.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Now I want to preview selected file without close minibuffer. In embark I'm not operation for this.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can't answer for Consult etc., sorry.

But [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) lets you display and visit any number of files in the same minibuffer, that is, for the same command invocation, e.g., `C-x 4 f`.

Icicles commands that access files are generally [multi-commands](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands), which means just that: you can act on any number of completion candidates in the same command invocation.

See [Icicles - File-Name Input](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input) for more info about Icicles commands that read file names.

Answer (score 0):

Since Embark itself does not have a preview function, you might be able to do it with `embark-consult`:

```lisp
(use-package embark-consult
             :ensure t
             :hook
             (embark-collect-mode . consult-preview-at-point-mode))
```

found at github [Embark: QuickStart](https://github.com/oantolin/embark#quick-start)

Comment: And how I can use it? What is keybinding to preview select file (without close miinibuffer)?